# Плохие стороны апплетов

Tags: веб-программирование, applet, java

Здравствуйте.
Кто знает, чем апплеты многих не *устраивают*, что их довольно редко используют? Вроде удобно впихнуть красиво сделанный апплет на страничку, которая будет уже выглядеть как красивое оконное приложение. Да и еще много плюсов, как мне кажется, есть у апплетов.
Расширю вопрос: что может еще очень хорошо на Web сделать красивый оконный интерфейс. Кроме ExtJS.

Comment: Апплеты не будут работать на девайсах Android и iOS никаким образом.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У пользователя должна стоять JVM (или хотя бы JRE). А сможете это гарантировать? И 10 лет назад скачать пусть и 20 мегабайт вирт.машины было проблематично.
А вдруг политика безопасности запрещает аплеты? Плюс ограничений у аплетов множество: писать что-то куда-то невозможно. Нативные методы не запускаются.

[Java-апплет](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java-%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82#.D0.9D.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.BE.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D1.82.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D0.B0.D0.BF.D0.BF.D0.BB.D0.B5.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2) - тут подробнее.

Comment: Хорошо. А если речь идет об использовании внутри предприятия? И если использовать <b>Java Web Start</b>?

Comment: Стоп. Апплеты запускаются в браузере, JWS'у браузер не нужен.
Внутри преприятия - это как раз тот случай, где они еще остались уверенно жить) хотя я видел реализацию на апплетах клиентских приложений в некоторых крупных банках.
апплеты чаще применяют, если уже есть огромное приложение, написанное на swing, и его нужно по какой-то причине перевести в веб-среду. А если писать с нуля, то у Хорстмана написано про сервлеты, jsp и специалисты постоянно пишут про java server faces

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Просто мне надо сейчас выбрать то, где я буду писать довольно сложное web-приложение внутри предприятия. И это приложение должно иметь ну очень уж динамичный интерфейс, примерно как windows-приложение. Ну вот и стоит выбор между ExtJS, JavaFX, Swing или еще чем-нибудь. И размышляю, на чем же писать: на Java или на JavaScript.
В этом-то и требуется мне помощь: в выборе лучшей среды

Comment: Хотелось бы еще и советы увидеть по этому поводу )

Comment: :)
а вам конкретно какие советы нужны?) с JSF и JWS я не сталкивался прямо. зато со свингом наработался отлично. так что со словами с википедии "разработка UI для аплета сложнее, чем на html" полностью согласен - нужно понимать, как построен свинг и знать пару отличных форумов, где можно задать вопросы))
Тут недавно еще новости про JavaFX были - но я не разбирался. Суть в том, что UI строится декларативно и отображается сразу же и на смартфонах, и на тачпадах и на обычном к-тере.

Comment: Ага. Не заметил превый комментарий.
Сейчас в мире очень сильно рулит AJAX(наверное, его и имели ввиду, говоря о JS). Как совет, сразу же скажу вам - используйте паттерн проетирования MVC или MVP. Тогда уже не суть важно что вы выберите - fx, jsp, jsf или gwt.
КСТАТИ! GWT! 
http://wiki.linuxformat.ru/index.php/LXF90:JavaEE - вот ссылка есть про всякие разные технологии. Для первого ознакомления.

Comment: Сама суть важна для меня в данной задаче - построить графический интерфейс, где можно будет создавать особые HTML-формы, которые впоследствии будут выводиться пользователю. Работа пользователей с ними будет происходить при активным взаимодействием с БД (т.е. данные на форме будут отправляться/приходить из БД). Ну вот и интересно, при помощи чего, как думает народ, наиболее эффективно можно будет справиться с данной задачей. То, что эта программа должна быть Web, - хочет заказчик. Использоваться она будет строго внутри предприятия.

Comment: Скорее всего вам стоит обратить внимание на Struts - он как раз занимается всякими формами активно.
С базами данных - тут, скорее всего, два выбора - либо по старинке jdbc самому настраивать, либо испольовать hibernate

Comment: Да, хорошая идея, Struts. Он, вроде, хорошо MVC реализует.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь уже упаминался GWT.Я тоже хочу обратить на него внимание.Очень навороченный фреймворк.Как нельзя лучше подходит для организации вэб-приложения предприятия.Из плюсов:

- легко делать интерфейс десктопного windows-приложения
- встроенные возможности для реализации MVP.Вместе с GIN и Guice
     это позволяет делать легко
     расширяемое и тестируемое приложение
- 100% AJAX,что делает работу в браузере схожим на работу с
     десктопным приложением+поддерживаются
     кнопки навигации в браузере
- встроенная кроссбраузерность(хотя для предприятия это не критично)
- клиентский и серверный код пишится на Java,не нужно заморачиваться с
     HTML и JavaScript

Comment: Замечательно! Всем спасибо! Закачался информацией) Осталось только начать.
А кто работал с GWT? Он случайно не слишком медленно компилируется или работает? Просто где-то слышал, что GWT довольно медленно работает.

Comment: Большие приложения могут медленно компилироваться (несколько минут). Выполняются достаточно прилично, если не городить бог знает что. HTML и JavaScript знать всё равно нужно - вам от них не уйти ;)

Comment: Все ясно, спасибо.